# Can't SSH into Linux web server

Tags: macos, ssh

I'm trying to connect to my newly purchased website on GoDaddy via SSH. However, when I try to connect from my Mac, I get the following error message:

```
$ssh username@website.com -v -v -v
OpenSSH_5.9p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8zg 14 July 2015
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to website.com [XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/UserName/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/UserName/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

When I initially tried connecting, I was prompted for a password. I entered my password, although it was apparently incorrect. After a few attempts, it stopped asking me for my password and started giving me the above message instead.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/804307/ssh-error-connection-closed-by-remote-host) has a very similar error message, although it's missing the `debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0` line. I tried the answers, although they did not fix my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the host had blocked me after I had failed too many login attempts. After contacting the network admins and getting me unblocked, I was able ssh in without any problems.